# Specifying HTML5 Audio Clip Sequences

Tags: html

I have the following simple HTML5 audio tag on my page and it's supposed to start at 2 hr, 17 min, 0 sec but it's just starting at the beginning:

```
<audio id="florence" src="Audio/Florence_Show-NYC.mp3#t=2:17:00" controls>Audio Not Supported</audio>
```

I'm currently running on Chrome (71.0.3578.98).  I believe I have the clip syntax correct but something's wrong.  Can't seem to get any clip sequence to work.  Would appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  In order for clips to work you MUST supply the leading 0's for all time values.  So, in my case, the time signature had to be 02:17:00, not 2:17:00.  With the leading 0's in place, it works.